# How do I grep only the word I gave as a variable?

Tags: bash

I want grep a word in my file, but only the part I gave to grep.

Example : in my file, i've "hell\nhell:o", i want grep hell but not hello.
How can I do that?

Comment: Like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206910/265109 ?

Comment: My bad, I misphrased my question, in fact in my file I have "hell\nhell:o" and I just want grep hell
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you can edit your question as you mentioned. You know, nobody is expected to look at the comments for possible clarifications on question body.

Comment: @Wizz Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to include the possible edge cases in the question itself. Some questions of mine: How do you discriminate between the first "hell" and the second "hell"? Alphanumeric characters? \b characters? Non-printables? Whitespace? (Otherwise, vahdet's finding seems like a suitable solution.) What have you tried and why does it not work?

Comment: So you want to match `hell`, but not `hell:o`... what about `hello` or `hell-o` or `hell_b`, etc...?

Comment: The difference between the two "hells" is that one a, at the end of the string":o" and the other not.

Comment: @Attie Exactly, i want just match hell, not hello, hell:o, hell-o, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
grep -E "\bhell(\s|$)" file
```

add `o` if you just want the matched word:

```
kent$  echo "hell\nhell:o"|grep -oE "\bhell(\s|$)"
hell
```

or:

```
grep -oP '\bhell(?=\s|$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the -o  option of grep  :

```
grep -o hell your_file
```

From grep manual page :

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Comment: I've already tried, but it gives me hell and hell, I just need him to give me hell

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-oP`

```
echo "hell hello" | grep -oP '\bhell\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question (and comments) aren't overly clear but you could try either:

- "*negative lookahead*"
- using the "*end of line anchor*"

---

## Negative Lookahead

The following regex will match any `hell` that isn't followed by a `:` (adapt as suitable):

```
hell(?!:)
```

`grep` doesn't support this, so you'll need to use `perl` or something else:

```
echo -e "hell\nhell:o" \
    | perl -ne 'print if /hell(?!:)/'
```

## End of Line Anchor

The following *will* work with `grep`, matching only where the `hell` touches the end of the line (`$`):

```
hell$
```

```sh
echo -e "hell\nhell:o" \
    | grep 'hell$'
```